# Referential integrity checking in table definition

Tags: sql, database, oracle, ddl

I have a table of `STUDENTS` which contains student information. Each student might or might not be a `CANDIDATE` in a college voting event, depending on the value of `CANDIDATE BIT`.

I'd like to have a table `VOTE` which keeps the votes of students, but I'd like to check if the student which is being inserted as `VOTES_FOR` is actually a `CANDIDATE` or not. In plain english: Check if the person being voted for is actually a candidate or not.

Any idea on how I can check for this constraint? I want to do this task using simple regular DDL commands not stored procedure and PL/SQL or T-SQL

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENTS(
    ID INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT = 1,
    FIRST_NAME NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
    LAST_NAME NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    CANDIDATE BIT DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);    
CREATE TABLE VOTE(
    STUDENT_ID references STUDENTS(ID),
    VOTES_FOR references STUDENTS(ID),
    PRIMARY KEY STUDENT_ID
);
```

Comment: i'm assuming that your goal is to prevent voting for non-candidates, is that correct? are you yourself constrained from preventing this in the application?

Comment: Yes that's right, I want to have in in table definition level, not in the application itself

Comment: I'm guessing you're using Oracle, by your mention of PL/SQL, is that right?

Comment: I am looking for the idea , not for the exact command , I want to know that if it's generally possible or not.

Comment: see my answer below; depending on the database, it can be achieved, but not through a simple declarative sql syntax. The Tony Andrews article give a very slick workaround.

Comment: The DDL you posted is not valid in Oracle (there is no `auto_increment`, there is no `bit` data type, for example).  It appears that you posted SQL Server syntax.  Are you sure that you're using Oracle and PL/SQL and not SQL Server and T-SQL?

Comment: @JustinCave , you are right , I just added the T-SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a UNIQUE constraint on the pair of columns "ID" and "CANDIDATE", and reference that pair from the table "VOTES". Use a CHECK constraint in "VOTES" to guarantee that votes are recorded only for a candidate.

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENTS(
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    CANDIDATE CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'f' NOT NULL 
      CHECK (CANDIDATE IN ('t', 'f')),
    UNIQUE (ID, CANDIDATE)
);

CREATE TABLE VOTES(
    STUDENT_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
      REFERENCES STUDENTS (ID),
    VOTES_FOR INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CANDIDATE CHAR(1) DEFAULT 't' 
      CHECK (CANDIDATE = 't'),
    FOREIGN KEY (VOTES_FOR, CANDIDATE)
      REFERENCES STUDENTS (ID, CANDIDATE)
);
```

"IS_CANDIDATE" is probably a better name than "CANDIDATE"; "CANDIDATE_ID" is probably a better name than "VOTES_FOR".

Comment: @mike-sherrill-catcall out of curiousity, is there a reason you used a char(1) versus a bit field? This definitely solves the issue, great answer.

Comment: a) Every dbms supports char(1). Most *don't* support bit data types. (That includes Oracle, your target platform.) b) The SQL:2003 standard dropped the bit type. c) Oracle doesn't support a Boolean data type in a CREATE TABLE statement.

Answer (score 2):

Right on for seeking a DDL solution for this type of problem.

I'd push towards incorporating a Candidate table.
My reasoning is this will allow you to declare unique traits such as start and end candidacy times that would enable a student to try to become a candidate the following year or later.

Also this gives you an ID for that candidate to refer to.

```
CREATE TABLE student {
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    fname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    lname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
};

CREATE TABLE candidate {
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    student_id INTEGER(11) NOT NULL,
    start_year INTEGER(4) NOT NULL,
    start_month INTEGER(2) NOT NULL,
    start_day INTEGER(2) NOT NULL,
    end_year INTEGER(4) NULL,
    end_month INTEGER(2) NULL,
    end_day INTEGER(2) NULL
}

CREATE TABLE vote {
    student_id INTEGER(11) NOT NULL,
    candidate_id INTEGER(11) NOT NULL
};
```

Comment: That involves creating a new table and managing that table is a problem itself, I'd like to know if this is possible generally or not

Comment: It is a DDL solution.

Comment: A Student is not a Candidate and I'm making the case that the DB should recognize this.

Comment: I'll add example schema.

Comment: Your current Candidate 'Bit' is acting as a Boolean for wither a student is a candidate. That is bad design and leads to the problems that lead to you creating this Q.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Oracle and the database you want to look into a [Ref Constraint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm#sthref2919) here's an exmample [Ref Constraint Example](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/clauses002.htm#i1015744)

Although the situation may be a little more complex than Oracle constraints allow for. This article written by [Tony Andrews](http://tonyandrews.blogspot.com/2004/10/enforcing-complex-constraints-in.html) provides an ingenious workaround for achieving your desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the SQL CHECK constraint?

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp

You're going to need a composite foreign key to provide the check you want.

Comment: Actually the problem is that I don't want to check the value of the foreign key itself , I want to check the value of `CANDIDATE` in a row which is being referenced, and I am confused, how composite foreign key may help us here ?